# Wrong TLS version

Tags: java, ssl, handshake, tls1.2

I am trying to establish a TLSv1.2 connection with the following parameters:

```
-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2
-Djdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3,SSLv2Hello,TLSv1,TLSv1.1
```

But with *-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake,verbose*  I always get

```
Thread-9, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 149
Thread-9, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
Thread-9, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
```

What could be the reason?  Tried on another env with same key and truststore and it works... sounds environmental. Anything with the JVM?

Comment: Are you sure the destination server supports TLSv1.2? You can check with tools like this one: https://www.htbridge.com/ssl/

Comment: What Java version is this using?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Java Criptography Extension jar files, downloaded from oracle site http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html (this is for JAVA7, you should download which you need), to your JAVA(used by your server)/jre/security/lib folder.
Let us know! Regards

Comment: Replace them with the bew ones